# Header shaking if you scrolling and the pointer is on the hero image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

My header is shaking uncontrolably when the user is scrolling and the pointer is on the hero image. You can find the page here: [page url](https://ct.tmmbuilds.com/curatetrips/basque-country-24-31aug-2021/). I have disabled the cache plugin and i have also update all the plugin on the site but still nothing. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the javascript that is changing the header height based on the amount the user has scrolled down the page. It would be helpful if you could include whatever function handles this in your question.